# Why do I get a SIGSEGV when I use my overloaded insertopm (<<) operator?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, segmentation-fault

I'm taking a C++ class, and for my most recent assignment, I have to create a `Box` class. Overall, the assignment has actually been a walk in the park, but I'm having some trouble with the overloaded insertion operator I am supposed to create. The insertion operator is declared in `box.h`, and defined in `box.cpp`, as is standard. In the `Box` class, I have a `print(std::ostream &) const` function. All the overloaded insertion operator does is call the `print` function on the `std::ostream &` provided to the operator. Relevant code:

```cpp
void Box::print(std::ostream &outStream) const { // The java in me loves abstraction
    if ((_boxType == BoxType::FILLED) || (_boxType == BoxType::HOLLOW))
        _printFilledOrHollow(outStream);
    else if (_boxType == BoxType::CHECKERED)
        _printCheckered(outStream);
}

void Box::_printFilledOrHollow(std::ostream &outStream) const {
    if (_width > 1) {
        outStream << string(_width, 'x') << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < (_height - 2); i++) { //works for everything but 1
            if (_boxType == Box::FILLED)
                outStream << string(_width, 'x') << endl;
            else
                outStream << "x" << string((_width - 2), ' ') << "x" << endl;
        }
        outStream << string(_width, 'x') << endl;
    } else
        outStream << "x" << endl; //which is what this is for
}

void Box::_printCheckered(std::ostream &outStream) const {
    if (_boxType == Box::CHECKERED) {
        for (int row = 0; row < _height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < _width; col++) {
                if ((row % 2) == 0) { // if even column
                    if (col % 2 == 0)
                        outStream << "x";
                    else
                        outStream << " ";
                } else {
                    if ((col % 2) != 0)
                        outStream << "x";
                    else
                        outStream << " ";
                }
            }

            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &outStream, const Box &rhs) {
    rhs.print(outStream);
}
```

Now, here's the really weird part. If I add something to the tune of `cout << "";` to the end of the `Box::print` function, it completes as intended, without the SIGSEGV. I'm completely and totally stumped by this, and was hoping you guys could at least clue me in to why this is happening. If necessary, I'll turn it it with `cout << ""` at the end of `Box::Print`, but I would really prefer to get a handle on this error. Thanks!

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, (eg. with `-Wall`) and you would have caught the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the return statement in your `operator`. In Java, it wouldn't even compile, but C++ is more “permissive” meaning that you get UB instead.

As @Eichhörnchen mentioned in the comment, enabling compiler warnings is a must-do when dealing with C++.

Comment: I feel pretty dumb... Thanks for noticing my stupid mistake